# Angular directive checking active or not

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is it possible to know whether dirictive active or not?
Such as if I have something similar code

```
<my-dir><my-dir>

<div ng-show='my-dir'></div>
```

This purpose is important for me when I comment out my directive inside of div should not shown. That's why I set ng-show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for that you must create a variable that checks which have an established directive, [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/YrcpbREp3CayxFEyjj8M?p=preview):

```
.directive("myDir", function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link:function($scope){
      $scope.myDir = true
    }
  }
})
```

```
<my-dir><my-dir>
<div ng-show='myDir'>on</div>
```

Or simplifying:

```
<my-dir ng-init="myDir = true"><my-dir>
<div ng-show='myDir'>on</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to use directive that would be using isolated scope, so that it could be used in multiple places, In that we need to pass `showDiv` variable that will work with two way binding of variable which is supplied in `show-div` attribute.

**Markup**

```
<my-dir show-div="myDir"><my-dir>
<div ng-show='myDir'>Content shown when directive is present</div>
```

**Directive**

```
.directive("myDir", function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope:{
       showDiv: '='
    },
    link:function($scope,element){
      $scope.showDiv = true; //div will shown when directive is present
      $scope.$on('$destroy', function(){
          $scope.showDiv = false; //div will get hidden when directive is removed or not present
      });
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: @Shaxrillo do you like this approach